# can I use visual studio 2013 (run on windows 8.1 ) to Create raspberry pi 2 app (RPI2 Running Windows 10 )?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

can I use  visual studio 2013 (run on windows 8.1 ) to Create raspberry pi 2 app (RPI2 Running Windows 10 ) ?

can I use windows 10 SDK in windows 8.1 and  visual studio 2013 ?  and do I need to use it to make RPI2 program ?

I can use any version of the visual studio but do not want to change Windows , What are your recommendations ?

/* note : my project base on raspberry pi GPIO */

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. You must use Visual Studio 2015 (the most recent is the RC version, [the RTM build will be available on July 20th](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2015/06/29/save-the-date-visual-studio-2015-rtm-on-july-20th.aspx)).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn609832.aspx#target_win10

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894631.aspx

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/universal-windows-platform-vs.aspx

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs.aspx

Comment: can I use Visual Studio 2015 in win 8.1 for RPI2 ? will I still need win 10 ? as I read in requirements I can  use Windows 8.1 or later

Comment: Yes you can install Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 8.1 and compile Universal Apps for ARM (Windows Phone, RPi2 etc.), however Windows 10 PC is needed to install Windows 10 on RPi2 http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SettingUpWindows10ForIoTOnYourRaspberryPi2.aspx

Comment: Thanks very very very much :) :) :) 
I have already installed Windows on my  RPi2

Comment: @Bartlomiej Actually, as of the 6/24 update the RPi2 preview includes a Win 7+ compatible flasher utility!  No more needing Win10 to flash & program a RPi2!   http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/ReleaseNotes.htm

Answer (score 0):

No, you need Windows 10 for that.

Source:
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-developer-tools

> 1. Install Windows 10 Insider Preview.
>      You’ll need a Windows 10 PC for all Windows 10 development. Join the Insider Program, and then follow the Insider Program’s instructions to install Windows 10 Insider Preview.